# Wrong bash script syntax

Tags: shell

I have a script part where I am checking **if** the file exist . I dont find where is my mistake because it jumps to else( file exists) and starts downloading that file. Part of code:

```
...
    if [ -f '$ins.img' ];
    then
        echo '$ins.img already exists'
    else
       wget http://$2/$ins/$ins.img
    fi
...
```

Comment: Variables don't expand in single quotes.

Comment: lol , i didnt know there is a difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you're using single quotes in your `if`. Variables are not filled in inside single quotes, so it will check for a file literally named `$ins.img`, which obviously doesn't exist.

The solution is easy, use double quotes.

Comment: Didnt know there is a difference of those. Thanks by the way :))